# Incorporating a link to a sprintf image

Tags: php

I am using the following code to output an image tied to a Wordpress post:

```
    if ( $cover ) :
        return sprintf(
                '<img src="%1$s">',
                $cover
            );
    endif;
```

This does output the required image but I need it to be clickable to display the image in full using:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $cover( 'medium_large' ) ) ?>">
```

Please can somebody advise how I can bring the two together?

Thanks.

Comment: Also note, that I am not the one that downvoted your question :)

Comment: Finally, remember to upvote my answer if it worked for you :) I will appreciate it a lot! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I don't know what your code does, or how are the variables defined, but this will generate the output you want:

```
function cover($cover = '') {
    if ( '' !== $cover ) :
        return sprintf(
            '<a href="%1$s"><img src="%1$s"></a>',
            $cover
        );
    endif;
}

echo cover('/path/to/my/image.png');
```

The above will output the following code:

```
<a href="/path/to/my/image.png">
    <img src="/path/to/my/image.png">
</a>
```

Keep in mind, that I do suppose you already know how to get the post cover image URL, and that's why I have make the function to accept the cover image URL only.

---

**Update #1**

If you want to display different sizes images when you click the link you could do the following:

```
function cover($cover_link = '', $cover_img = '') {
    if ( '' !== $cover ) :
        return sprintf(
            '<a href="%1$s"><img src="%2$s"></a>',
            $cover_link,
            $cover_img
        );
    endif;
}
```

And then use the function `cover` inside the WordPress loop as following:

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();

        // ... HTML or PHP Code you need for your loop

        $cover_link = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), 'full');
        $cover_img = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), 'post-thumbnail');

        if ( $cover_link && $cover_img ) {
            echo cover($cover_link, $cover_img);
        }

        // ... HTML or PHP Code you need for your loop
    }

}
```

---

**Update #2**

In the above example, I've used the image sizes `full` and `post-thumbnail`. In case you need to have custom sizes for your uploaded images you could use in the `functions.php` code like the following:

```
add_image_size( 'my_big_image_size', 1000, 1000, true);
add_image_size( 'my_small_image_size', 500, 500, true);
```

And then, inside the loop, you could change the following code:

```
$cover_link = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), 'full');
$cover_img = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), 'post-thumbnail');
```

To this:

```
$cover_link = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), 'my_big_image_size');
$cover_img = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), 'my_small_image_size');
```

Comment: I hope your problem has been solved now :) Enjoy ;)

Comment: The one element that is missing is that upon click the image opens the same size as is displayed, rather than full size.

Comment: Using WordPress functions you can do what you need. If you need to register custom sizes for images in WordPress you could use the `add_image_size` function. Then you have to re-generate the images, and you have sizes other than the initial sizes. See here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/

Comment: If you need to load a different size image, you could use the `wp_get_attachment_image_url` but this function requires you to know the attachment image ID. More here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_url/

Comment: Otherwise, if you want to display the thumbnail of a single post in different sizes, you could use the function `get_the_post_thumbnail_url`. More here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/

Comment: Well you more than earned your tick, thank you so much.